# Unable to determine session size using Session.getSizeInBytes()

Tags: wicket

I am trying to determine the size of my session, which I want to track as I start to make a development change. My application runs fine normally with no serialisation errors - except when I try to get the session size.

In Wicket 1.4, I recall that I had no problem, but now I cannot do it. I get the same error if I get the session size in my `PageBase` constructor.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

### Java code

```
public class PageBase extends WebPage
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ...
  @Override
  protected void onAfterRender()
  {
    super.onAfterRender();

    Session ssnSession = Session.get();
    long loSize = ssnSession.getSizeInBytes();    <-- Exception is raised here
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

### Stack trace

```
11-Jul-2012 19:30:11 org.apache.wicket.util.lang.WicketObjects$SerializingObjectSizeOfStrategy sizeOf
WARNING: Unable to determine object size: [...].MySession@d2f5f1
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.WicketObjects$SerializingObjectSizeOfStrategy.sizeOf(WicketObjects.java:124)
  at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.WicketObjects.sizeof(WicketObjects.java:416)
  at org.apache.wicket.Session.getSizeInBytes(Session.java:439)
  at [...].PageBase.onAfterRender(PageBase.java:212)
  at org.apache.wicket.Component.afterRender(Component.java:962)
  at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2326)
  at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1035)
  at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105)
...
```

### My software environment

- Web framework: Wicket 1.5.7
- Java: 1.6.0_33; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.8-b03
- Web server system: Google App Engine for Java version 1.7.0
- Operating system: Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition version 2002 SP3 (version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_GB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my problem using

```
dev_appserver.cmd --jvm_flag=-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

to highlight the offending data member. In my `WebSession` instances I used

```
private final Object m_objLockItemPaidStatus = new Object();
```

to lock processing in a `synchronized` block. I have changed this to use an instance of

```
/**
 * This class is the simplest possible class which can be used as an object
 * to lock processing in a <code>synchronized</code> block
 * and which can also be serialised.
 * (This class extends <code>java.lang.Object</code> solely to implement the
 * <code>java.io.Serializable</code> interface.)
 */
public static class LockObject extends Object implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public LockObject()
  {
    super();
  }
}
```

instead, in order to ensure that my `WebSession` instances can be serialised (and so I can find their approximate sizes too using `WebSession#getSizeInBytes()`).

One thing strange to me is that since I expect Wicket to serialise my `WebSession` instances in my Google App Engine for Java (GAE/J) environment, why was this not picked up already using the GAE/J development web server?